# Calling Controller from Tiles Template using Spring 3

Tags: spring, templates, tiles2

I just set up Apache Tiles 2 in my Spring MVC 3 application.

I created my template :

```
 <definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/baseLayout.jsp">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Template"/>
      <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="menu"   value="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="body"   value="/WEB-INF/jsp/body.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="footer"   value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp"/>
  </definition>
```

and a Welcome page :

```
  <definition name="welcome" extends="baseLayout">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Welcome"/>
      <put-attribute name="body"   value="/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp"/>      
  </definition>
```

And the properties for tile :

```
welcome.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
welcome.url=welcome
```

And my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home() {
    logger.info("Welcome home yesssssss!");
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    logger.info("Loading Companies");
    mav.addObject("companys", companyService.loadCompanys());
    mav.setViewName("welcome");
    return mav;
}
```

It works fine.

But how do i call another controller from within the template file like say **menu.jsp**
that will call a controller like this one :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/menu", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView menu() {
    logger.info("get MEnu");
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    logger.info("Loading menu");
    mav.addObject("menu", menu.get());
    mav.setViewName("menu");
    return mav;
}
```

Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call the 'menu' controller, you need to specify the 'menu' in your properties file together with a corresponding url, which has to be mapped to the controller (just like you did for the welcome).

May I suggest to use .htm for views or .do for forms etc.?
Without, it's easy to get confused if you're trying to show a view, or you're trying to map a Request etc.